# Linkedin API : Could not find a CSRF state token in the request

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, linkedin-api

I would like to create a local application in **php (CodeIgniter)** that allows to manage my Linkedin account.

**I installed this library:** [Happyr Linkedin Api Client](https://github.com/Happyr/LinkedIn-API-client/)

I followed the same instructions, but I have an error message when redirecting after successful log in.

```
 Type: Happyr \ LinkedIn \ Exception \ LinkedInException
Message: Could not get access token: The user may have revoked the authorization response from LinkedIn.com was empty.
Filename: C: \ wamp \ www \ linkedin \ vendor \ happyr \ linkedin-api-client \ src \ Authenticator.php

Line Number: 128
```

**When I comment line 128, I get another error:**

```
Message: Could not find a CSRF state token in the request.

Filename: C: \ wamp \ www \ linkedin \ vendor \ happyr \ linkedin-api-client \ src \ Authenticator.php

Line Number: 208
```

Please help me solve this problem.
Thank you :)

Comment: Commenting out line 128 isn't a good idea. You need to pass access token to library.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
Just can you tell me how can i do it ?

Comment: I can't, you didn't show us any of your code.

Comment: @AdamDev did you found solution?